# SQL Mirroring - Queries to confirm health and to check back log

Tags: sql, t-sql, database-mirroring

I'm after any sql queries that might be out there for being able to confirm the health of a mirror i.e working or failed.  Also if there is a query out there where you can view current backlog.

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Have you done any research on this? Have you tried googling the question and looking at the different sources of information regarding SQLServer mirroring (Like [SqlServerCentral](http://www.sqlservercentral.com))? Mind elaborating on what you have tried or looked at?

Comment: Hi - yes I've been doing my research. Most results are around MirrorMonitor. I need the sql to put in a sp or straight in to a job. I've come up with query below..select * from sys.database_mirroring where mirroring_state_desc = 'SYNCHRONIZED'. Also I think I can use unsent log as indication for backlog. Not sure what size for unsent log is acceptable as wouldn't want an alert for blips in comms between pri and mirror site.  Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will get all details of mirroring:

EXEC sp_dbmmonitorresults [Database Name] , [Lat x hours results] ,[Does not update the status for the database]

Example:

USE msdb;
EXEC sp_dbmmonitorresults AdventureWorks2012, 2, 0;

This code get last 2 hours details.